# I used backbone.js to render the view and successfully fetched the data, but it didn't seem to be visible on firefox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a Backbone.js front end for a rest api and I am running into a problem.  I have been able to pull the data from the api and put it into a single portDetailListview and the problem is that the data is definitely there. However, it will not display when the page loads. I have researched a lot and can't find anything that relates directly to this and I am a beginner with Backbone.js, so it's possible I may be going about this the wrong way.   Any help would be appreciated.   Here is my code:
**main.js**

```
`statisticDetails:function (id) {
        console.log("switching to single switchmonitor view")
        var stl = st.get(id);
        $('#content').html(new StatisticMonitorView({model:stl}).render().el);
        $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
        $('li > a[href*="/statisticmonitor"]').parent().addClass('active');
    },

tpl.loadTemplates(['home', 'status', 'topology', 'header', 'switch', 'switch-list', 'switch-list-item', 'host', 'host-list', 'host-list-item', 'port-list', 'port-list-item', 'flow-list', 'flow-list-item', 'statisticmonitor', 'statisticmonitor-list-item', 'policy-list', 'policy-list-item', 'portdetail-list', 'portdetail-list-item', 'switchdetail'],
    function () {
        app = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
        //console.log("started history")
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // trigger Backbone routing when clicking on links, thanks to Atinux and pbnv
            app.navigate("", true);
            window.document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e = e || window.event
                var target = e.target || e.srcElement
                if ( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a' ) {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    var uri = target.getAttribute('href')
                    if (uri.substr(0,4) !== 'http') {
                        app.navigate(uri.substr(1), true)
                    }
                    else {
                        parent.window.location.assign(uri)
                    }
                }
            });
            
            window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
                //loctaion.pathname
                app.navigate(location.pathname.substr(1), true);
            });
            
            // wait for the page to be rendered before loading any data
            swl.fetch();
            hl.fetch();
            st.fetch();
            pl.fetch();
            
            setInterval(function () {
                if(updating) {
                    swl.fetch();
                    hl.fetch();
                    
                    st.fetch();
                    pl.fetch();
                    
                }
            }, 3000);
        });
    });`
```

**StatisticMonitor.js**

```
`window.StatisticMonitorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    
    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('switchdetail'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("remove", this.render, this);
        //this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        
        // some parts of the model are large and are only needed in detail view
        this.model.loadPortDetails();
        //this.model.loadChart();
    },
    
    render:function (eventName) {


        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); 
        $(this.el).find('#portdetail-list').html(new PortDetailListView({model:this.model.portdetails}).render().el);
        
        return this;
    },
}); `
```

**StatisticMonitorModel.js**

```
`window.StatsSwitch = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/wm/trafficCollector/",
    
    defaults: {
        dpid: '',
        portNumber: '',
    },
    
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        
        self.trigger('add');
        this.portdetails = new PortDetailCollection();
    },
        
    fetch: function() {
        this.initialize()
    },
    loadPortDetails: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self);
        console.log(self.attributes.dpid);
        console.log(self.attributes.port);
        
        $.ajax({
            url: hackBase + "/wm/trafficCollector/switchportstats/" + self.attributes.dpid + "/" + self.attributes.port + '/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("switch detail:" + self.attributes.dpid + self.attributes.port );
                //console.log("fetched  switch port detail list: " + data.length);
                console.log(data);
    
                self.portdetails.add({
                    rxbytes: data[0].switch_statistic.rxSpeed,
                    txbytes: data[0].switch_statistic.txSpeed,
                    updatetime: new Date(data[0].switch_statistic.time)
                        .toLocaleString()
                })
    
            }
        })
    
    }
    
    
    `
});
```

**PortDetail.js**

```
`window.PortDetailListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"tr",

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('portdetail-list-item'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    //this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },
    
    render:function (eventName) {
        console.log("port detail list item");
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});


window.PortDetailListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('portdetail-list'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("add", this.render, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        //$(this.el).html(this.template({nswitches:swl.length}));//this.model.length or swl.length
        
        _.each(this.model.models, function (pd) {
            $(this.el).find('table.portdetail-table > tbody')
            
            
                .append(new PortDetailListItemView({model:pd}).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

});`
```

**switchdetail.html**

```
`<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>chart</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Switch: (<%= id %>) /port:(<%= port %>)</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div id="container-chart" style="width:800px;height:400px"></div>
        
        <div id="portdetail-list"></div>

    </div>
</div>`
```

**portdetail-list.html**

```
`<div class="page-header">
    <h1>PortDetail</h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped portdetail-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rxbytes </th>
            <th>Txbytes</th>
            <th>updatetime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- portdetail-list-item infor will be inserted here by PortdetailListItem:render -->
    </tbody>
</table>`
```

**portdetail-list-item.html**

```
 `  <td><%= rxbytes %></td>
    <td><%= txbytes %></td>
    <td><%= updatetime %></td>`
```

I try to print this command"console.log(this.model.toJSON());" to see if I get the data, The result of this command is Object { rxbytes: "3087", txbytes: "3430", updatetime: "2023/5/11 14:33:44" }
So I'm wondering if I've got the data, why can't the view see it

```
`window.PortDetailListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:"tr",

    initialize:function () {
        this.template = _.template(tpl.get('portdetail-list-item'));
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    //this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },
    
    render:function (eventName) {
        console.log("port detail list item");
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }

});`
```